# I need help with this circuit!

Tags: arduino

I have an arduino uno r3 that runs on 5 volts. I'm trying to build something similar to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ElZec033vQ this circuit but I'm having a hard time figuring out what type of resistors, transistors, mechanical relay, and diode to get. The whole point of this circuit is to create a small repetitive pulse. I can't conclude what type of materials to get. Can someone please help me! I really appreciate it.

Comment: I'm not sure if everything done in the video is necessary. Just try pulling the circuit high and low quickly. And let the IO pin drive a transistor (via a sensible resistor of course).

Comment: Do you think a 330 ohm resistor would work? Thank btw.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, this is the schematic of what he's doing in the video, don't take any of the parts numbers here as correct, these are just default values from circuit lab.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0TuMK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This seems to be overly complex to me, however I would recommend experimentation to figure out the simplest circuit that works. Start with just connecting an output pin from the Arduino to the pennies and setting it high and low as  Bradman175 suggests.

If that doesn't work I recommend toggling the pin between input and output, setting it low whenever it's an output. This should be essentially the same as what the relay is doing, only rather than a full open circuit between the pennies and ground when the relay is off, you're getting an input impedance of around 100 megohms whenever the pin is configured as an input.

If this doesn't work try upgrading to the relay and diode, the diode acts as a flyback diode so it is necessary to protect the Arduino from voltage spikes. Turn the relay on and off with the Arduino rather than with a transistor, the reason for a transistor is just because the relay the guy was using in the video probably needed more than 30 mA of forward current to be powered. Most relays do require a large amount of current to work, however if you buy a relay module online made to be triggered by an Arduino or similar microcontrollers, you should be fine. Most relay modules also come with built in flyback diodes so you can also get buy without one of those if you buy a module.

If you can't find any 5 volt relays that trigger on less than 30 mA and don't want to use a relay module, you will have to build the whole circuit. I didn't do any reasearch to find a proper 5 volt MOSFET for this circuit, but if you have any lying around they should do as long as they're n-channel MOSFETs that can deliver enough current to drive whatever transistor you buy (500 mA would be plenty). If you feel more confortable with NPN transistors than MOSFETs you can always replace the MOSFET in the circuit with an NPN if you have those lying around instead. This would basically mean directly replacing the MOSFET with an NPN, with the collector connected to the input of the relay, emitter grounded, and base connected to the 100 ohm resistor.

The 100 ohm resistor is used with the MOSFET despite the MOSFET having extremely high input impedances because of stray capacitance that exists between the gate and source which causes nano second shorts every time the pin goes high, and between the drain and gate which causes nano second shorts every time the pin goes low. With a resistor this protects the Arduino from possible damage.

Comment: Thank you for a feed back! I'll let you know if I encounter anything. I'm really thankful for your feed back and your effort into helping me achieve something! Really appreciate it :D